# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 65: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, anaconda, decode

I'm trying to read a geotiff with rasterio.read(),and this error came out.

Here is the code in Python Console:

`In[2]:import rasterio`
`In[3]:rasterio.open('E:\\TreeSatAI\\Abies_alba_0_2545_WEFL_NLF.tif')`

```
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 65: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 65: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 61: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 61: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 60: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 60: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 65: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 65: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 70: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 61: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 61: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 60: invalid continuation byte
Exception ignored in: 'rasterio.\_env.log_error'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\\Anaconda\\envs\\Latest\\lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\env.py", line 326, in defenv
local.\_env.start()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 60: invalid continuation byte
```

`Out[3]: <open DatasetReader name='E:/TreeSatAI/Abies_alba_0_2545_WEFL_NLF.tif' mode='r'>`

The more confusing thing is that opening a fake address, this UnicodeDecodeError still came out as same.So all I know about this is a environment problem. Does it ralate to Windows system?

Here is my environment:

```
dependencies:

- attrs=23.2.0=pyh71513ae_0
- blas=1.0=mkl
- blosc=1.21.3=h6c2663c_0
- boost-cpp=1.74.0=h5b4e17d_6
- bottleneck=1.3.5=py39h080aedc_0
- branca=0.7.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
- brotli-python=1.0.9=py39h415ef7b_7
- bzip2=1.0.8=h8ffe710_4
- ca-certificates=2023.11.17=h56e8100_0
- cairo=1.16.0=haedb8bc_5
- certifi=2023.11.17=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- cfitsio=3.470=h2bbff1b_7
- charset-normalizer=3.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- click=8.1.7=win_pyh7428d3b_0
- click-plugins=1.1.1=py_0
- cligj=0.7.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
- colorama=0.4.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- cycler=0.12.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- expat=2.5.0=h63175ca_1
- folium=0.15.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- fontconfig=2.14.1=h9c4af85_2
- freetype=2.10.4=h546665d_1
- freexl=2.0.0=hd7a5696_0
- gdal=3.6.2=py39h7670e6c_4
- geopandas=0.14.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- geopandas-base=0.14.2=pyha770c72_0
- geos=3.8.0=h33f27b4_0
- geotiff=1.7.0=h4545760_3
- giflib=5.2.1=h8d14728_2
- glib=2.69.1=h5dc1a3c_2
- hdf4=4.2.13=h712560f_2
- hdf5=1.12.1=h51c971a_3
- icc_rt=2022.1.0=h6049295_2
- idna=3.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- importlib-metadata=7.0.1=pyha770c72_0
- intel-openmp=2024.0.0=h57928b3_49840
- jinja2=3.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- joblib=1.3.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- jpeg=9e=h8ffe710_2
- kealib=1.5.0=hde4a422_1
- kiwisolver=1.4.4=py39hd77b12b_0
- lcms2=2.12=h83e58a3_0
- lerc=3.0=hd77b12b_0
- libblas=3.9.0=12_win64_mkl
- libcblas=3.9.0=12_win64_mkl
- libcurl=8.5.0=h86230a5_0
- libdeflate=1.17=h2bbff1b_1
- libexpat=2.5.0=h63175ca_1
- libffi=3.4.2=h8ffe710_5
- libgdal=3.6.2=h9a21643_4
- libiconv=1.17=h8ffe710_0
- libkml=1.3.0=h9859afa_1014
- liblapack=3.9.0=12_win64_mkl
- libnetcdf=4.8.1=h6685c40_4
- libpng=1.6.39=h8cc25b3_0
- libpq=12.15=h906ac69_0
- libspatialindex=1.9.3=h39d44d4_4
- libspatialite=5.1.0=hbdd3232_0
- libssh2=1.10.0=he2ea4bf_2
- libtiff=4.5.1=hd77b12b_0
- libwebp=1.3.2=hbc33d0d_0
- libwebp-base=1.3.2=h2bbff1b_0
- libxml2=2.10.4=h0ad7f3c_1
- libzip=1.8.0=h289538f_1
- lz4-c=1.9.4=h2bbff1b_0
- m2w64-gcc-libgfortran=5.3.0=6
- m2w64-gcc-libs=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gcc-libs-core=5.3.0=7
- m2w64-gmp=6.1.0=2
- m2w64-libwinpthread-git=5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
- mapclassify=2.5.0=py39haa95532_0
- markupsafe=2.1.3=py39h2bbff1b_0
- matplotlib-base=3.4.3=py39h581301d_2
- minizip=4.0.3=hb68bac4_0
- mkl=2021.4.0=h0e2418a_729
- mkl-service=2.4.0=py39h6b0492b_0
- msys2-conda-epoch=20160418=1
- numexpr=2.8.4=py39h5b0cc5e_0
- openjpeg=2.4.0=h4fc8c34_0
- openssl=3.0.12=h2bbff1b_0
- packaging=23.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- pcre=8.45=h0e60522_0
- pcre2=10.42=h0ff8eda_0
- pip=23.3.1=py39haa95532_0
- pixman=0.40.0=h2bbff1b_1
- poppler=22.12.0=h0bf3bde_3
- poppler-data=0.4.12=hd8ed1ab_0
- proj=9.3.1=ha107b6e_0
- pyparsing=3.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- pyproj=3.6.1=py39h8d66fa9_0
- pysocks=1.7.1=pyh0701188_6
- python=3.9.18=h1aa4202_0
- python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- python_abi=3.9=2_cp39
- pytz=2023.3.post1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- qhull=2020.2=h70d2c02_2
- requests=2.31.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- rtree=1.2.0=py39h09fdee3_0
- setuptools=68.2.2=py39haa95532_0
- six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
- sqlite=3.41.2=h2bbff1b_0
- tbb=2021.8.0=h59b6b97_0
- threadpoolctl=3.2.0=pyha21a80b_0
- tiledb=2.3.3=hd8964de_3
- tk=8.6.12=h2bbff1b_0
- tornado=6.2=py39hb82d6ee_0
- urllib3=2.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
- vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
- wheel=0.41.2=py39haa95532_0
- win_inet_pton=1.1.0=pyhd8ed1ab_6
- xerces-c=3.2.4=hd77b12b_1
- xyzservices=2023.10.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- xz=5.4.5=h8cc25b3_0
- zipp=3.17.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
- zlib=1.2.13=h8cc25b3_0
- zstd=1.5.5=hd43e919_0
- pip:
  - affine==2.4.0
  - filelock==3.13.1
  - fiona==1.9.5
  - fsspec==2023.12.2
  - huggingface-hub==0.20.2
  - mpmath==1.3.0
  - networkx==3.2.1
  - numpy==1.26.3
  - pandas==2.1.4
  - pillow==10.2.0
  - pyyaml==6.0.1
  - rasterio==1.3.8
  - safetensors==0.4.1
  - scikit-learn==1.4.0
  - scipy==1.11.4
  - shapely==2.0.2
  - snuggs==1.4.7
  - sympy==1.12
  - timm==0.9.12
  - torch==2.1.2+cu121
  - torchaudio==2.1.2+cu121
  - torchvision==0.16.2
  - tqdm==4.66.1
  - treesat-benchmark==0.1.0
  - typing-extensions==4.9.0
  - tzdata==2023.4
```

This code is a part from a paper that I try to reproduce.I am sure that environments was built as the papaer claimed.
I tried to change different version of python(3.9/3.10) and rasterio(1.3.7/8/9), but it didn't work.
I changed global and project encodeing in PyCharm-Settings-Editor-Code Style-File Encodings, FAILED.
I used `rasterio.open(path,encoding='utf-8/latin-1/ISO-8859-1')`,FAILED.

Is there a solution that do not need to use Linux?